# day view algorithm

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Does anyone know how can I implement the display of overlapping appointments?

Basically I'm using silverlight but if you have algo there, just share it.

Comment: what do you mean by overlapping of appointments? do you want solution to display overlapping appointments?

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding, I edited my question. It should be the displaying of appointments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no single algorithm - a scheduler control (if that's what you're looking for) is a quite complex entity. There is [a community sample](http://www.silverlight.net/community/samples/silverlight-samples/silverlight-scheduler-35867/) (Silverlight) that shows how to do something like this - pretty sure you won't have a problem re-implementing the same element on WP7 as long as you have some Silverlight development experience.

Also, ComponentOne [has a control](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/SchedulerSilverlight/) that does this - since it is based on Silverlight, I am sure it is fairly easy to adapt it to a Windows Phone 7 application as well.